# Trouble understanding $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z} = \infty$ in complex

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is it true, that $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z} = \infty$$ for
>   $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I have some trouble with a definition of this. I know that in $\mathbb{C}$ we have only one point at infinity unlike in $\mathbb{R}$ where we have $\pm \infty$. Could somebody provide me with a definition of the above limit?

Comment: Surely you mean $z\to 0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Of course. Sorry!

Comment: Yes - $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z) = \infty$ if for every $M>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)|>M$, whenever $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$. In your example, simply take $\delta = 1/M$.

Comment: It's not really a definition but maybe it will help you understand the definition, we say that $\lim_{z\to a} f(z) = \infty$ if $\lim_{z\to a} |f(z)| = + \infty$.

Comment: @markmcclure Apparently those named Mark think alike.  I was wrote my solution and just noticed thereafter that your comment.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV And I just upvoted your answer. :)

Comment: @markmcclure Thank you Mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac1z =\infty$ means that for all $B>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $$\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|>B$$whenever $0<|z|<\delta$.

With $\delta=1/B$, we are done.

Answer (score 3):

If
$z = x+iy$,
$\frac1{z}
=\frac1{x+iy}
=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}
=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}
$.

If
$y = \sqrt{x}$,
then,
as $x \to 0$,
$\frac1{z}
=\frac{x}{x^2+x}-i\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+x}
\approx 1-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$,
so the real part is bounded
while the imaginary part blows up.

Similarly,
if $x = \sqrt{y}$,
 the imaginary part is bounded
while the real part blows up.

In all cases,
the magnitude of
$\frac1{z}$
blows up as
$|z| \to 0$.

Comment: I was going to write something tantamount to this, but thought I'd stick to the definition.  (+1) my friend.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't looked at it in this way before, so I found it interesting that the real part or the imaginary part can be bounded.

Comment: Indeed.  Complex analysis is rich with interesting "stuff."